# find and replace html contents from remote iframe

Tags: php, html, regex, iframe

Extract of the captured iframe code from remote host.

```
  <div class="ad-title">
                        <span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('surfv.php?view=surfer&f=1&t=f97e5cec351c254254c290577e6a&p=78r254sfsv46s224&u=1','_blank');">Link1 Name</span>  
                    </div>

        <p class="adimg"><img src="http://domain.com/banner_7.png"  style="max-height:50px; max-width:200px;;border:0px;"/></p>
                               <div class="ad-content">



        <table cellpadding="5" width="100%"><tr>
             <td valign="top"><span style="font-family:  Verdana, Sans-serif; font-size:13px; ">Add title</span></td>
             </tr>
             </table>
                    </div>
```

Earn 
                                            $ 
                                        0.0005

---

I have captured remote iframe and read the code.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://remotehost.com/iframe.php');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

---

extract of the code is shown above

I want to capture

```
surfv.php?view=surfer&f=1&t=f97e5cec351c254254c290577e6a&p=78r254sfsv46s224&u=1
```

Link1 Name
$0.0005

from this frame and put them in a new table in the following format.
New link =`http://mywebsite.com/surfv.php?view=surfer&f=1&t=f97e5cec351c254254c290577e6a&p=78r254sfsv46s224&u=1

```
NewLink Title= Link1 Name
Price= $0.0005
--------------
```

Thanks for help`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function gsb($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini    = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://remotehost.com/iframe.php');
$link="http://mywebsite.com/".gsb($homepage,"window.open('","'");
echo $link;
```

Comment: thanks for the help- i will try it and then come back.

Comment: its has many occurrences for  window.open('surfv.php ... I tried to implement the code but it does not capture the required links else it capture the first link with window.open('surfv.php and displays it ... thanks for more suggestions

Comment: its takes the link that displays after window.open(   -- I want to capture links starting with surfv.php? ,,and modify it ... thanks for more suggestions.